# How does an affine connection permit differentiation of vector fields?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

As I understand it, one primary use of affine connections is to "connect" tangent spaces. 
Suppose I take a velocity vector $\dot{\gamma}(t_0)$ on a curve and at some point $\dot{\gamma}(t)$ also on that curve,where $t = t_0 +h$. One might then consider taking the derivative

$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{ \dot{\gamma}(t_0+h) - \dot{\gamma}(t_0)} {h}$

But apparently this doesn't work since nearby tangent spaces are different spaces. So we need an affine connection to "connect" nearby tangent spaces to permit differentiation of vector fields.

I provided a definition of an affine connection here:

[Breaking down what the definition of an affine connection says](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084302/breaking-down-what-the-definition-of-an-affine-connection-says)

**My Question**

How exactly does the definition of an affine connection allow me to then differentiate vector fields? I don't understand how an affine connection improves what we know about the relationship between the tangent spaces to permit differentiation.

Comment: As a starting point, you might try reading my answer to a similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099619/covariant-derivative-geometric-interpretation).

Comment: Indeed, that was helpful. So question: when we say we differentiating in the direction of X, that means the vector field X as defined at a point p? So at that point, it would just be a vector in the tangent space at the point p, and in this sense it makes sense to say in the "direction" like in vector calculus or tensor calculus. Is that correct? I've never understood why people say with respect to the vector field X because it makes it sound like its with respect to the entire vector field over the whole manifold, which would be devoid of any notion of a single direction.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are vector fields, so is $\nabla_X Y$; but as you suggest, the intuition is that $(\nabla_X Y)(p)$ is the derivative of $Y$ in the direction of $X(p)$ at the point $p$.

Comment: @StanShunpike: At each point over a manifold, a vector field is a tangent vector, that gives you a direction. This association is *smooth*

Comment: @janmarqz and why is that important? I'm just curious. Smoothness seems to be an important criteria for many reasons so I am wondering why you mention it here.

Comment: this is to capture "change of directions" in a neither so abruptly approach nor discontinuos: *smooth variation*

Comment: @janmarqz and, correct me if I am wrong, that by definition means the vector field satisfies the conditions for differentiability

Comment: where ever you talk about, any involved function has derivatives